# результат выполнения функции

Tags: php, ооп

есть класс, внутри которого две функции. первая функция возвращает значение переменной, которое используется как параметр для второй функции

пример:

```
class example{
  function f1(){
    $v;
    //some code
    retutn $v;
  }

  function f2($param){
    echo $param;
  }
}

$obj = new example;
$n = $obj -> f1();
$obj -> f2($n);
```

это то, как я смог реализовать.
но можно ли сделать как-то так

```
class example{
  function f1(){
    $v;
    //some code
    retutn $v;
  }

  $n = f1();

  function f2(){
    echo $this -> n;
  }
}

$obj = new example;
$obj -> f1();
$obj -> f2(); //и тут напечатался бы результат выполнения первой функции
```

то есть, можно ли как-то передать значение параметра уже внутри класса, что б при вызове второй функции не указывать входящий параметр?

Comment: Не понятно почему сразу не выполнить f2(), а в ней вызвать f1()? Или будет много функций типа f1() и нужно будет каждый выбирать какую из них вызывать?

Comment: @cheops, честно говоря, не пришла такая мыль в голову... думаю, это как раз то, что мне нужно. потому что для каждой f2() нужен результат выполнение f1() именно своего объекта. спасибо

Comment: Заводите свойство ....например `$data` и результат первой функции складируете туда `$this->data = 123765123651237;` ; а во второй  пользуетесь этой переменной

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, то есть, примерно так? 
`$data;
$this->data = $this->f1();`

Comment: в классе `private $data = null;`........ первая функция `function f1(){
    $v;
    //some code
    $this->data = $v;
  }` .....вторая `function f2(){
    echo $this->data;
  }` .......а все остальное без изменений `$obj = new example;
$obj -> f1();
$obj -> f2();` .........https://ideone.com/JtG4jq   ....... а если вам нужно `для каждой f2() нужен результат выполнение f1()`  то тогда можно делать как cheops сказал. Это правильнее будет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо! все заработало как АК-47

Comment: я просто еще забыл уточнить, что кроме f2() в классе есть есть f3() и f4(), для которых тоже нужен результат выполнения f1(). мне кажется, не совсем удобно внутри каждой f2(), f3(), f4() выполнять f1(). поэтому ваш вариант, @АлексейШиманский, мне подходит больше, чем вариант cheops. всем спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Хочу обратить Ваше внимание на один нюанс, который называется *temporal coupling*. Многие (большинство? все?) методы Вашего класса зависят от результата работы метода `f1()`. Вызов `f2()`, должен предваряться вызовом `f1()` для корректной работы приложения. Т.е. другим разработчикам, которые будут работать с Вашим классом, нужно постоянно держать в уме эту деталь реализации, которая, к слову, никак не следует из интерфейса. Т.е. разработчик придет к пониманию этого порядка либо прочитав документацию, либо путем проб и ошибок, либо покопавшись в исходном коде Вашего класса. Это все признаки плохого дизайна класса. Ведь получается, что экземпляр класса после своего создания не сконфигурирован для выполнения методов `f2()`, `f3()` и т.д. Трудно что-то сказать в отрыве от конкретной задачи, но я бы сначала ответил бы на ряд вопросов:

1. Имеет ли смысл существование экземпляра класса без вызова `f1()`?
2. Имеет ли смысл вызов `f2()` вне контекста состояния объекта (обрабатывая скажем скалярное значение на входе)?
3. Являются ли методы `f2()`, `f3()` etc. обязанностью этого класса? Или может метод `f1()` должен возвращать должным образом сконфигурированный объект другого класса, который уже сможет обрабатывать `f2()` и `f3()`?
4. Имеет ли для системы ценность результат работы `f1()` вне контекста состояния объекта?

Возможно будет разумно уже в конструкторе ожидать аргумент для `f1()`, и записывать в поле объекта результат, гарантируя, что при вызове других методов объект будет сконфигурирован. Может все таки стоит провести декомпозицию класса, разграничивая обязанности, может это сделает систему гибче и более расширяемой. Скорее всего для вашей задачи это оверкил, но советую проводить подобного рода анализ всегда, когда сталкиваетесь с подобными проблемами - это типичный code smell, признак плохого дизайна, не придать этому значения при разработке важного системообразующего модуля - с высокой вероятностью увеличить грядущие издержки на поддержку системы.

Comment: спасибо за рекомендацию, не могу не согласиться с вашими словами и приму их к сведению в будущем. данная же задача решается, скажем, забавы ради, набиваю шишки. никакого практического использования класса не будет. а суть, на самом деле, в том, что под f1() я подразумевал подключение к серверу, а в под f2() и f3() - выбор базы и выполнение запроса. написал свой класс работы с бд для сокращения числа передаваемых параметров в стандартных функциях